# unpacking, editing and rebuilding ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to edit the contents of a ruby gem, call him ***a.gem***.
I used `gem unpack a.gem` ,got the insides of it, and `gem unpack --spec a.gem` to get a *.gemspec*.
I've added a new file, updated the `files:` section of the *.gemspec* to include it. 
I've put *a.gemspec* inside the folder resulted from unpacking the gem. 
Now I'm try to `gem build a.gemspec`, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid gemspec in [logstash-output-jdbc-5.2.1-java.gemspec]: logstash-output-jdbc-5.2.1-java.gemspec:1: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification
                 ^
logstash-output-jdbc-5.2.1-java.gemspec:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
name: logstash-output-jdbc
     ^
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.
```

What am I doing something wrong? I'm not a ruby programmer and I just need to edit something there.

Answer (score 2):

A little late for OP, but these steps worked for me.  Perhaps they'll help someone else:

```sh
gem spec pkg-1.2.3.gem --ruby > pkg.spec
gem unpack pkg-1.2.3.gem
mv pkg.spec pkg-1.2.3
cd pkg-1.2.3
gem build pkg.spec
```

Need the `--ruby`, otherwise the spec file is yaml.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simpler workflow

```
gem open my_gem
```

This will open the installed gem's source code in your EDITOR. Make your edits. Save, restart your app to see the effects.

Comment: I do this often for adding debug printing into gems.

Comment: I'm trying and getting "Unable to find gem 'gemName'".

Comment: @sel: enough with the fake gem names. Show the exact command you're running and its output, _verbatim_.

Comment: C:\Users\jeff\Desktop\logstash>gem open logstash-output-jdbc-5.2.1-java
Unable to find gem 'logstash-output-jdbc-5.2.1-java'

Comment: @sel: but the gem name is `logstash-output-jdbc`. Try that.

Comment: @sel: so, how did it go?